# How to change label color on button click Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
<Label Text="pass or username is incorrect" TextColor="Red" x:Name="FailureResult" IsVisible="false"/>
```

What should i write in the else

```
if ((await UserManaging.ReadAllAsync()).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name && x.Password == pass) != null)
{
  await Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
}
else
{
  
}
```

I want it to look like this but only after the pass or username is mistaken

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to change the color, just the visibility

```
FailureResult.IsVisible = true;
```